# Anyone know about the use of the skull for magic in the Burmese traditions?

Tags: traditions

I am doing research on the Burmese Weikza traditions and wanted help as to the usage of the skull in their magical practices.

Answer (score 1):

Peter

What ever magical practice that might be, it has nothing to do with the Buddha, Dhamma an the Sangha and is called "Animal Art" by the Buddha and a grave misconduct.

[Wrong livelihood for contemplatives](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than_en.html#livelihood)

So maybe the question is better placed outside of "Buddhism"

Skulls an [bones are used as object of investigation and meditation](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/buddhadasa/dhammawithpictures_en.html#22), asuba-nimitta (object of unattractiveness), to gain high concentration if done right. Of coures such training in what is called Jhana, can lead to [supranatural powers](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.11.0.than_en.html#drawbacks) but such is not the aim just side effects of practicing.

*(Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purposes or other worldly gains.)*

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which I think asks "how are they used?" and not "should they be used?". According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weizza) this maybe *is* associated with "Buddhism in Burma", and is therefore on-topic on this site. I'm not asking you to recommend that people practice it, and of course you don't have to answer this question, but it is on-topic on this site. Also "it is misconduct" might be considered as advice, and not as an answer -- see [Answers vs Advice](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254) for guidelines on that topic.

Comment: One might find that keeping an useful and healthy discussion in Buddhism, especially one that does not require strong and constant moderation, might require leaving some more outlying subjects out of the discussion.

Comment: Open a chat, it you like to discuss., @ChrisW . Or delete it, if it does not fit to your refuge. It's a gift.